# No route matches [DELETE] (How to build a to do app in rails 4 youtube tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Title says it all, I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

To do list controller:

```
 class TodoListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @todo_lists = TodoList.all
  end


  def show
  end


  def new
    @todo_list = TodoList.new
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @todo_list = TodoList.new(todo_list_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.update(todo_list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @todo_list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Todo list was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_todo_list
      @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
    end


    def todo_list_params
      params.require(:todo_list).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

Comment: What are you passing to link_to in your view?

Comment: <div class="links">
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_todo_list_path(@todo_list) %> |
  <%= link_to 'Delete', todo_lists_path(@todo_list), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> |
  <%= link_to 'Back', todo_lists_path %>  
</div>

The issue actually started after I added the delete option.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `routes.rb` file has something like this

```
resources :todo_lists
```

or

```
delete "/todo_lists/:id" => "todo_lists#destroy"
```

The link should be

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', todo_list_path(@todo_list), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Comment: It's there.


' Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todo_lists do
    resources :todo_items do 
      member do
        patch :complete
      end
    end
  end
  
  root "todo_lists#index"
  
end
'